# Loading Oracle ctl export file into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration, sql-loader

I have a number of tables exported from an oracle database in the form of Ctl files with that data included within the file.

Im looking for a way to import these into postgresql but the the enterprise db toolkit seems to want a direct link to an already running oracle instance. A program similar to sql-loader would be excellent.

Comment: What do you mean "exported from an oracle database in the form of Ctl files with that data included within the file."?  Exactly how were these files created?  Most db products have a utility to import a simple csv file.  That's what oracle's sqlldr does.

Comment: I'm not trying to load then into oracle so sqldr doesn't help me.

Comment: I know that you are not trying to load oracle.  My point is that most products, and I'm guessing postgre is no different, have a utility _like_ sqlldr to load simple csv files into their database.  A simple csv file, not a "Ctl files with that data included within the file.", whatever that is.

Comment: @EdStevens is trying to get more information from you about how exactly you generated these "ctl" files. As far as know, a [Control](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/control.htm#ADMIN11282) file isn't actually a database backup. Did you use something like Original Export/Import, Data Pump Import/Export, Full Transportable Import/Export or similar? Do you have a utility that will let you do a CSV export instead? Because that is a lowest common denominator and much easier for data import tools to use.

Comment: I didn't generate them and they are what I have to work with.

Comment: If your controlfile has data, it will be prefixed with BEGINDATA, so technically you can use a SED command to delete all lines till BEGINDATA and that would give you a delimited file. Which you can then load to pgSQL db.

Comment: If you can't explain how they were created or what the _actual_ format is then they could be anything in any format, and there is no way anyone could advise on how to use them.  In the oracle world, a 'ctl' file in this context would mean a file used as parameter input (may or may not include data) for sqlldr.  But that is not created by "exporting" anything (even a loose use of the term 'export') so it is still completely unclear what you have.

Comment: @EdStevens if you don't know what a Ctl file is please go away. There has only been one constructive comment so far from raj who at least had the sense to look up oracle cal file before he opened his mouth. I can load them into an oracle database with no problems but want to move them to oracle without having to create an intermediary database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to load the data into oracle and then use one of the migration toolkits to move it to Postgres. Oracle produce a number of virtual box VMs that limit the effort needed but its still an extra step.